# Filtering by MongoDb Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

How to filter an array from the database by date, for example from "2021-03-04T23: 00: 00.000Z" ~ "2021-04-05T22: 00: 00.000Z"?

```json
orders: {
  followers: 100,
  orderCreationDate: "2021-03-21T13:30:32.807Z",
  orderStatus: "play",
  tarifCost: 4,
  taskId: "127",
  totalOrderValue: 1000,
  userName: "rttt",
  _id: "60574a788b96cb2f3e359eab"
}
```

```js
const orders = await User.aggregate([
     { $unwind: '$orders' },
     { $match: { 'orders.orderStatus': { $not: /In Cart/ } } }
])
```

I'm trying to sort it like this, but why doesn't it work?

```js
      const users = await User.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$orders' },
        //   { $match: { 'orders.orderCreationDate': {
        //     $gte: ISODate("2021-03-021T23:00:00.000Z"),
        //     $lt: ISODate("2021-03-022T23:00:00.000Z")
        // }}},
        // { $match: { 'orders.orderStatus': { $not: /In Cart/ }}},
        // { $match: { 'orders.orderCreationDate': $lt: ISODate("2021-03-022T23:00:00.000Z")}}},
        {$and:
          [
            { 'orders.orderCreationDate': {$gte: ISODate(`2021-03-10T20:41:00.051+00:00`)}},
             { 'orders.orderCreationDate': {$lte:ISODate(`2021-03-26T20:41:00.051+00:00`)}}
           ]
         }
        // {  $and: [
        //     {
        //         $gte: [ 'orders.orderCreationDate', ISODate(`2021-03-18T21:07:42.313+00:00`) ]
        //     },
        //     {
        //         $lte: [ 'orders.orderCreationDate', ISODate(`2021-03-24T21:08:42.313+00:00`) ]
        //     },
        // ]}

       ])
```

My failed attempts.Nothing works

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far? What isn't working? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66807581/edit) your question to include details.

Comment: Hello there! Based on your comment to the answer below, you might want to adjust your question. It seems what you are asking for is "filtering" rather than sorting (maybe you also want sorting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB query language operators are type sensitive.  If the document field contains a string like

```
orderCreationDate: "2021-03-21T13:30:32.807Z"
```

You will need to query it with a string, like

```
 { $match: { 'orders.orderCreationDate': {$gte: "2021-03-021T23:00:00.000Z", $lt: "2021-03-022T23:00:00.000Z"}}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fezkbKOvF4y)

Comment: check the playground link

Comment: What to check? I don't quite understand

Comment: The playground link in my answer is showing the sample document provided, the aggregation you stated you wanted.  Is that not working?

Comment: If you remove filtering by dates, then the correct answer comes.
```const users = await User.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$orders' },
        { $match: { 'orders.orderStatus': { $not: /In Cart/ }}},
    ])
```

Comment: You mean like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/XWGs4ElkpLW

Comment: Yes, it works, but for me it is not stored as a string, but as a date. Maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: In the question you showed it as a string, if it is actually a date, wrap both strings in ISODate(), like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zUGrNuqofQ-

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `$sort` stage to your aggregation

```
{
    $sort: {
      "orders.orderCreationDate": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but this is not what I want. I would like to sort from some date to some date

Comment: Did you mean "match" or "select" instead of "sort"?

Comment: @Joe I mean "select"